# Run a nested query in Log Analytics

Tags: azure, performance, azure-log-analytics

Is it possible to run a nested query in log analytics?  I'm trying to get 2 timecharts (disk throughput and IOPS) from 2 querys running at the same time.  Is this possible?

This is both querys I'm trying to run at the same time:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk"
| where CounterName == "Disk Bytes/sec"
| where Computer contains "servername"
| summarize ThroughputInMBs = (max(CounterValue) / 1024 / 1024) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
| render timechart

Perf
 | where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk"
 | where CounterName == "Disk Transfers/sec"
 | where Computer contains "servername"
 | summarize ThroughputInMBs = (max(CounterValue)/1024/1024) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
 | render timechart
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run a nested query in log analytics?

- Yes, [Nested queries](https://www.cloudsma.com/2020/01/extracting-nested-fields-kusto/) are possible in Log Analytics.
- But you cannot run 2 queries at a time.
- I have tried to run the 2 queries at once , but got the error

```cs
Perf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk"
| where CounterName in ("Disk Bytes/sec","Disk Transfers/sec")
| summarize ThroughputInMBs = (max(CounterValue) / 1024 / 1024) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
| render timechart
```

[image]

- Use the below query to get the 2 charts

```cs
Perf
| where (CounterName == "Disk Bytes/sec" or CounterName == "Disk Transfers/sec")
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by strcat(Computer, " ", CounterName), bin(TimeGenerated, 10s)
| render timechart
```

[image]

### Update

- We cannot run multiple queries and display more than 1 chart or result in  Azure Log Analytics at once.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you're time and answer but in my case I was looking to generate the disk Throughput and the IOPS in separate charts.  Is that possible?

Comment: Even if the query results are combined, we cannot have more than one chart at a time. The best solution is to use `Azure Monitor Workbooks` to display the two charts side by side or one after the other,so that we can compare easily

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As of now log analytics does not support the output of 2 charts at the same time.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks but you're answer does not solve the problem, since  charts at the same time is not supported.

Comment: You can raise a ticket at [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/ "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/") or at [azure log analytics github](https://www.google.com/search?q=azure+log+analytics+github&oq=azure+log+analytics+gi&aqs=edge.1.69i57j0i512j0i390l2j69i60j69i64.6033j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "https://www.google.com/search?q=azure+log+analytics+github&oq=azure+log+analytics+gi&aqs=edge.1.69i57j0i512j0i390l2j69i60j69i64.6033j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=utf-8")